# How to use other classes as members of a class?

Tags: c++, class

I have the following class which inherits from Renderer which calls the derived `setup` and `draw` methods at a certain point.

```
class Application : public Renderer
{
private:
    float currentFrame, lastFrame;
    Model nanoSuit;
    ShaderProgram modelShaders;
public:
    Application(int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
        : Renderer{ windowWidth, windowHeight }, currentFrame(0), lastFrame(0) {};
    virtual ~Application();

    virtual void setup();
    virtual void draw();
};
```

Then I have this `setup` method:

```
void Application::setup()
{
    ... // shortened

    modelShaders = ShaderProgram{ modelShdrs };
    ... // shortened

    nanoSuit = Model{ modelPath.generic_string() };
}
```

How should I use the classes `Model` and `ShaderProgram` inside `Application` taking into account I don't want these classes to have their destructors called and I need to use them in other places like `draw`. Should I use `new` and get them on the Heap? Should I use a pointer?

**EDIT**

```
Application app{ SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT };

app.run();
```

The `setup` method is called inside `run` which is defined in the abstract class `Renderer`, after the application has successfully been initialised.

Comment: May be instead of copies use references. Using `std::shared_pointer` to do this could be a good idea.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But then I still need to initialise them inside the constructor and I want to do it in the setup function.

Comment: The first comment applies very well to that need.

Comment: Why do you want to use `setup` instead of the constructor?  The constructor's job is to initialize your object.

Comment: @StephenNewell because the `setup` is called at a specific place, after the application (not the class) has been initialized correctly. If I do it on the constructor and the initialization fails, it will load everything up before the failure.

Comment: No matter what you do, members will be initialised (i.e. one of their constructors called) in the process of constructing an `Application`.The only difference is that, if you don't explicitly initialise them in the initialisation list of `Application`s constructor, the compiler will call the default constructors (the one without arguments) of the members anyway, if they exist. That means your `setup()` should not be trying to initialise the members since they are already initialised - it should be changing state of those already-initialised members. Which also means not destructing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer, I'm assuming you can't change the `Renderer` class, or the pattern of using it (construct an instance of your `Application` that is derived from `Renderer`, then call its `run()`, which in turn calls `Application::setup()`).

Firstly, you have to realise that the members of `Application` are constructed when `Application` is constructed.   Your constructor may

> ```
> Application(int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
>     : Renderer{ windowWidth, windowHeight }, currentFrame(0), lastFrame(0) {};
> ```

may not list the members `nanoSuit` and `modelShaders` in its initialiser list but the standard requires they are constructed anyway.  This will use their default constructor (the constructors of `Model` and `ShaderProgram` that can accept no parameters).    If those types have no such constructors (or they are inaccessible) that will be a diagnosable error - in other words, the code for `Application`s constructor would not compile.

In your question, a `setup()` function is described, which I paraphrase here

> ```
> void Application::setup()
> {
>       modelShaders = ShaderProgram{ modelShdrs };
>       nanoSuit = Model{ modelPath.generic_string() };
> }
> ```

This function actually constructs a `ShaderProgram` object, assigns it to `modelShaders`.    However, that assignment is implemented (in `ShaderProgram`) the consequence is that there are two instances of `ShaderProgram` in existence (the member of `Application` named `modelShaders`, and the temporary you have created on the right hand side).    That temporary must be destroyed so (regardless of whether its members are copied or moved into `modelShaders`) its destructor must be called.

A similar thing happens for the statement that assigns `nanoSuit`.

Your options from here depend on what operations your classes support.   At the start of `Application::setup()` both `modelShaders` and `nanoSuit` are default-constructed.

So, instead of constructing temporary objects to initialise them, you need to set the state of those objects directly.   For example;

```
 modelShaders.setModelShdrs(modelShdrs);
 nanoSuit.setGenericString(modelPath.generic_string();};
```

Obviously, this only works if your `Model` and `ShaderProgram` classes provide the appropriate member functions to set their state.

Now, if the `Model` and/or `ModelShader` classes don't support such operations, you need to defer the construction of your objects.    One way to do this is to use `std::unique_ptr`  (from `<memory>`) like;

```
class Application : public Renderer
{
private:
    float currentFrame, lastFrame;
    std::unique_ptr<Model> nanoSuit;
    std::unique_ptr<ShaderProgram> modelShaders;
public:
    Application(int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
        : Renderer{ windowWidth, windowHeight }, currentFrame(0), lastFrame(0) {};
    virtual ~Application();

    virtual void setup();
    virtual void draw();
};
```

This will work since `std::unique_ptr`s default constructor initialises it with no contained object.

Now that we've gone out of our way to delay the construction of the actual instances of `Model` and `ShaderProgram` (i.e. not actually constructing objects of those types  in the process of constructing an `Application`) your `setup()` needs to actually construct them.   For example;

```
void Application::setup()
{
      modelShaders = new ShaderProgram{ modelShdrs };
      nanoSuit = new Model{ modelPath.generic_string() };
}
```

or (equivalent setup once done but different mechanism of getting there)

```
void Application::setup()
{
      modelShaders.reset(new ShaderProgram{ modelShdrs });
      nanoSuit.reset(new Model{ modelPath.generic_string() });
}
```

Because of all this `modelShaders` and `nanoSuit` are now (smart) pointers that manage the actual objects, so operations on them must change to use pointer syntax  (e.g. instead of `modelShaders.operation()` you must do `modelShaders->operation()` or `(*modelShaders).operation()`).

Since you are constructing the instances of `ShaderProgram` and `Model` for `Application` at this point  (rather than creating a temporary object to initialise existing objects) no extra destructor call will happen.

All this also assumes that `modelShaders` and `nanoSuit` will not be used before the call of `Application::setup()`.    This is the "can't have your cake and eat it too" assumption - delaying construction of the actual objects means also delaying when you can use the objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter! That's a thorough explanation, exactly what I was looking for. In the end I went with the `shared_ptr` variety and creating functions like the `setModelShaders`. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Model` and `ShaderProgram` as Singleton Class and use it whenever you want.

PFB example:

```
Class Model
{
   private: 
           Model() {  } //C-tor
           Model(const Model& rhs) { } //Copy Constructor
           ~Model() { } //D-tor
           static Model* instance;
   public: 
           static Model* getInstance() 
           {
               if(instance == NULL)
                      instance = new Model();
               return instance;
           }
   };
   Model* Model::instance = NULL;
```

If you want to use "Scott Meyers Singleton Approach" you can use as below.

```
class Model{
public:
   static Model& getInstance(){
   static Model instance;    
   return instance;
}
private:
Model()= default;
~Model()= default;
Model(const Model&)= delete;
Model& operator=(const Model&)= delete;
};
```

However, if you are using multithreading, you need to look for thread-safe implementation.

Above Singleton, Implementation is not thread-safe. Scott Meyers implementation is thread-safe if you are using C++11 & higher version of C++

Now you can also have similar Singleton class for `ShaderProgram` and can use in your function like:

```
void Application::setup()
{
    ... // shortened

    modelShaders = Model::getInstance()->getmodelShaders();//Required method to call
    ... // shortened

    nanoSuit = Model::getInstance()->getGenericStrings(); //Required method to call
}
```

I hope above helps as it will not call the destructor of `Model`

Comment: The _Singleton Pattern_ is probably not so good advice. There are several drawbacks, and it's generally not considered good designe. Also your proposed singleton implementation is horribly flawed, if ever go witth Scott Meyer's singleton implementation approach.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for your comment.

Singleton Implementation is given above just for the reference.This is not complete implementation.
As he wanted to use the same object in several places and don't want destructor to get called.